# OS X: How to show all files in chooser dialogs

Tags: macos

On OS X 10.5 and 10.6 at least, the command to enable all files in Finder only affects Finder Windows -- the "/File /Open" dialogs on applications still show a limited set of files, ignoring nearly all the Unix stuff.

Is there a setting which enables ALL file dialogs of ALL types to show ALL files?  I really am a big boy and promise not to harm them! :)

Comment: If you're a big boy, why are you using the GUI? ;-)

Comment: Dang! <shrinks down to original size>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command - Shift - . when the dialog is open.